# FreeIMU External Magnetometer

Tags: quadcopter, imu, calibration, magnetometer

I have been using the FreeIMU library successfully but now I want to add an external magnetometer that I can mount away from my motors.

I've figured out how to modify the FreeIMU library to use an external magnetometer and I am getting data.

What I can't figure out is what I need to change now that my magnetometer orientation has changed.

On the free IMU it is mounted like this 
[image]

The external compass is mounted like this - upside down - rotated 180° around x
[image]

I am changing the value inside the

`void HMC58X3::getRaw(int16_t *x,int16_t *y,int16_t *z)
{
    *x = cache_x;
    *y = cache_y;
    *z = cache_z;
}`

function as all the other code calls this to get the magnetometer data.

So far I have tried:

1. Changing the sign for the y and z values after I have got them from the magnetometer.
2. Changing the sign for the y value only
3. Changing the sign for the z value only
4. Added 180 to both the y and z values
5. Subtracting 180 from both the y and z values
6. Subtracting 180 from y and adding 180 to Z
7. Adding 180 to y and subtracting 180 from z
8. Changing nothing

The calibration GUI gives always gives me strange results, and doing the changes above just rotated/mirrored the magnetometer red and green graphs. I am unable to get rid of the key hole shape.
[image]

The red is XY. The green YZ. The blue is ZX. Does the fact that ZX works mean that my issue is with the Y value?

This is how it looks using the on board magnetometer.
[image]

What should I try next?

Thanks
Joe

EDIT

I tried rotating the external magnetometer so it is in the same orientation as the FreeIMU magnetometer and I still get the same result so I don't think its the difference in orientation that is causing the problem.

So then I thought maybe its because the FreeIMU is mounted central to the rotation axis and the external magnetometer is mounted about 20cm above. I tested this by rotating only the external magnetometer around itself and I still got the same result.

This is all seems strange, do you think its possible that the external magnetometer I have brought is faulty? Any way to confirm it is working properly on its own?

Thanks

EDIT

Managed to get circles plotting by changing the gain from 0 to 1. It seem my new magnetometer was being saturated.

Now I just need to work out how to change my values around so the orientation is correct.

Answer (score 2):

OK so I managed to solve this by doing a couple of things.

1. Connect external magnetometer to the same I2C bus as the FreeIMU.
2. The FreeIMU is 5V and the external magnetometer is 3.3V so I had to use a level shifter to place both devices on the I2C bus.
3. Change this line "accgyro->setI2CBypassEnabled(1);" to "accgyro->setI2CBypassEnabled(0);" to enable the external magnetometer
4. Change this line "magn->calibrate(0, 8);" to magn->calibrate(1, 8);" to increase the gain and remove saturation (this is what caused the strange "Keyhole" shape on the graph.
5. Calibrate the sensors.
6. Change this line

"AHRSupdate(val[3] * M_PI/180.0, val[4] * M_PI/180.0, val[5] * M_PI/180.0, val[0], val[1], val[2], val[6], val[7], val[8], magn_valid);"

to

"AHRSupdate(val[3] * M_PI/180.0, val[4] * M_PI/180.0, val[5] * M_PI/180.0, val[0], val[1], val[2], val[6], -val[7], -val[8], magn_valid);"

to account for the change in orientation.